# How does one use Fluid Simulation offset number correctly? Blender 3.1

Tags: export, import, fluid-simulation, drivers

**Desired Goal**

- Use the offset in the Fluid Simulation Panel to read in 1 or more frames for the 3D View Window.  Reuse the mesh data created from a fluid simulation.  A Read Only status is desired.

---

**Current Flawed State**

- The offset has worked periodically and is under suicide watch.  That is an  [update]. When the offset is changed I may see nothing even when going to a different frame.  The default zero value works.  Sometimes the cache mesh is deleted unexpectedly, apparently I know the magical sorcery to do so.

---

**Actions Taken Thus Far**

- File Import

  - Use
    [.obj] file format for mesh creation in the cache panel.
  - Less preferable. Export the data to .obj format using the export menu choice.
  - Import the .obj file format data created above from the file menu.
    This converts a single frame .obj file to a mesh. This has more Read Only behavior.  At the moment this has some value.
- Duplicate a fluid domain in the same scene.  This does not provide read only capability.  Append library possible.

---

An **offset** number exists in the UI for fluid simulation.. I have not used it successfully. I do not see a UI for using a **driver** with this data.  Other items nearby do have the [add driver] menu choice.

I want to use a portion of a completed fluid simulation.
Files have been copied and renamed.

Is there a way to tell Blender to
**[Read Only]**
the mesh data?  Never delete any data files.

The User can copy a fluid domain and  repeat the display.

Answer (score 1):

From the Documentation:

> Offset Frame offset that is used when loading the simulation from the
> cache. It is not considered when baking the simulation, only when
> loading it.

So, it seems like offset is for the case when you have already baked a simulation, the total bake frames exceed the shot length and you want to offset the start frame when the bake is being read and displayed.

Like if you wanted a 500 frame simulation to start 1 second later in a 24fps scene, you would enter "24" into this value.

Additionally, you must set the Type to *Modular* and rebake in order to use this setting correctly.

[image]